# How can I deploy a node.js app to azure via git when the app is in a subfolder?

Tags: node.js, git, azure

I have a existing git repository for a solution made up of multiple projects, some .Net, some Node.js. I want to deploy some of those projects to Azure Web sites via git.

Deploying an ASP.Net project living in a subfolder was [easy (see Scott Hanselman's blog post)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingTWOWebsitesToWindowsAzureFromOneGitRepository.aspx)  using a `.deployment` file:

```
[config]
project = WebProject/MyFirstSiteWebProject.csproj
```

Is there similar way to deploy a Node.js project living in a subfolder to Azure via git push?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's basically the same, except you set `project` to the folder instead of the csproj file. e.g.

```
[config]
project = SomeFolder
```

See [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-folder-for-a-node-php-or-aspnet-site) for details.

Comment: A bit more details: does the web.config on the root have to the nodejs handler? or can it all be inside the subfolder? I just tried this way but azure is still not picking up the subfolder